# Referencing to figure using label yields question marks

Tags: cross-referencing

This is my document. I can't seem to find out why referencing to this label only yields **??** rather than a reference. Other figures are working as intended.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pageanchor]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{P-waarde bij de chi-kwadraattoets}

\textbf{\textit{Let op!}} Deze paragraaf is geen stof die je moet weten, maar alleen ter verduidelijking!

\lipsum[1]\ref{fig:CS.CFG}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\capstart
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    xlabel = $\chi ^2$,
    ylabel = $P\left(\chi ^2 (5) \geq \chi ^2\right)$,
    samples = 200,
    restrict y to domain = 0:0.5,
    domain = 0.01:15]
    \foreach \k in {5} {%
      \addplot+[mark={}] gnuplot[raw gnuplot] {%
    isint(x)=(int(x)==x);
    log2 = 0.693147180559945;
    cchisq(x,k)=k<=0||!isint(k)?1/0:x<0?0.0:igamma(0.5*k,0.5*x);
    set xrange [ 1.00000e-10 : 15.0000 ];
    set yrange [ 0.00000 : 1.10000 ];
        samples=200;
        plot 1-cchisq(x,\k)};
}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Kansfunctie (Chi-kwadraat CDF) om een bepaalde waarde van $\chi ^2$ te vinden}\label{fig:CS.CDF}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Your labels don't match. You're referencing `fig:CS.CFG` but the figure label is `fig:CS.CDF`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot an answer? or too localized? :)

Comment: @cmhughes Seems a bit short for an answer :-) but I'm not sure it really counts as too localized. I'll add it as an answer and leave it up to others to decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Converting my comment into an answer.)

You're labels don't match. You're referencing `fig:CS.CFG`

```
\lipsum[1]\ref{fig:CS.CFG}.
```

but the figure label is `fig:CS.CDF`

```
\caption{Kansfunctie (Chi-kwadraat CDF) om een bepaalde waarde van 
$\chi ^2$ te vinden}\label{fig:CS.CDF}
```

You just need to correct the misspelt one, for example:

```
\lipsum[1]\ref{fig:CS.CDF}.
```